# Query Parent's record where condition on a Grandchild

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to select all the `Site_Report` entries where `Asset_Calcert` has at least one entry with condition `Asset_Calcert.Cert_type == 3`. The relationships are 1-0..* as shown below.

[image]

How do I go about it if want to put conditions on multiple entities, in my case I want to put condition on both Parent and Grand child. i.e `Site_report.report_status == 2`  and `Asset_Calcert.Cert_type == 3`

I've tried something like following, but not doing it right as it giving error with this approach.

```
IEnumerable<Site_Report> model;
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    model = ctx.Site_Report.Include(i => i.Published_By)
                            .Include(i => i.Handled_By)
                            .Include(i => i.Report_Assets.Select(c => c.Asset_Calcerts))
                            .Where(report => report.report_status == DBConstant.REPORT_STATUS_CONCLUDED)
    // Error ------>     // .Where(rp => rp.Report_Assets.Where(c => c.Asset_Calcerts.Any(d => d.cert_type == 3)))
                            .OrderByDescending(o => o.publish_date);
}
```

*Error*

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.collection.Generic .IEnumerable' to 'bool'.
>   Error   CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

**Modal** Only adding necessary fields for brevity

```
    public class Site_Report
    {
        public int site_report_id { get; set; }
        public int report_status { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public virtual ICollection<Report_Asset> Report_Assets { get; set; }

        public Site_Report()
        {
            this.Report_Assets = new HashSet<Report_Asset>();
        }
    }

    public class Report_Asset
    {
        public int report_asset_id { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public int site_report_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Site_Report Site_Report { get; set; 

        public Report_Asset()
        {
            this.Asset_Calcerts = new HashSet<Asset_Calcert>();
        }
    }
    public class Asset_Calcert
    {
        public int asset_calcert_id { get; set; }
        public int cert_type { get; set; }

        // Navigation Properties
        public int report_asset_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Report_Asset Report_Asset { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Aarif i've updated the question

Comment: what's the problem with this? aren't you getting required results or something else?

Comment: maybe try doing query from `Asset-Celert`, I don't have the Models so assuming the navigation properties

`ctx.Asset_Calcerts.Where(x=>x.Cert_type == 3).Where(x=>x.ReportAsset.SiteReport.report_status==DBConstant.REPORT_STATUS_CONCLUDED).OrderByDescending(o => o.publish_date);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Queryable.Where` uses a predicate parameter. The predicate is usually written in the format:

```
report => Some expression that takes report as input, and a Boolean as output
```

Your predicate is:

```
rp => rp.Report_Assets.Where(c => c.Asset_Calcerts.Any(d => d.cert_type == 3))
```

So your expression is:

```
rp.Report_Assets.Where(c => c.Asset_Calcerts.Any(d => d.cert_type == 3))
```

The value of this expression is not a Boolean, it is a `IQueryable<ReportAssert>`! Surely visual studio will have told you so when you hovered your mouse over it?

You wrote: I want to select all the Site_Report entries where Asset_Calcert has at least one entry with condition Asset_Calcert.Cert_type == 3

Or in a little re-wording:

> **Requirement**: I want all (or some) properties of all SiteReports that have at least one ReportAsset that has at least one AssetCalCert where AssetCalCert.CertType equals 3

If you want to select properties of "a sequence within a sequence", you use SelectMany instead of Select:

```
var result = myDbContext.SiteReports

   .Where(siteReport => siteReport.ReportAssets.SelectMany(reportAsset => reportAsset.AssetCalCerts)

       // I only want this siteReport if at least one of the AssertCalCerts
       // has a certType value equal to 3
       .Any(assertCalCert => assertCalCert.CertType == 3))

   // from the resulting SiteReports selecte the properties that you plan to use:
   .Select(siteReport => new
   {
       Id = siteReport.Id,
       Name = siteReport.Name,
       ...

       ReportAsserts = siteReport.ReportAssets.Select(reportAsset => new
       {
           Id = reportAssert.Id,
           ...

           AssetCalCerts = reportAsset.AssetCalCerts.Select(assetCalCert => new
           {
             ...
           })
           .ToList(),
       })
       .ToList(),
  };
```

> When querying data, always use Select and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only use Include if you plan to update the fetched item.

If SiteReport [10] has 1000 ReportAssets, then every ReportAsset will have a foreign key to ths SiteReport with a value 10. It would be a waste to transfer the same value 10 more than a 1000 times.

### Anonymous types

Note that I used anonymous types:

```
siteReport => new
{
    ...
}
```

Of course I could have used `new SiteReport()` instead. But if I'd used that I would have transported several variables that I don't plan to use. Of course I could just skip filling the properties that I don't use, but if my readers get a `SiteReport` object, they may expect that all values are filled.

So while it is more efficient to use an anonymous type, the disadvantage is that you can't use the anonymous type as a return value. If you need to do that, the best way would be to separate the class that represents the database table from the class that represents fetched data: (adapter design pattern? or facade?)

```
class AdaptedSiteReport()
{
    ... only properties that queriers plan to use
}
```

And in the LINQ statement

```
siteReport => new AdaptedSiteReport() {...}
```

The advantage of separating the actual database from the fetched representation is that you can change the internal database representation without users having to notice it.

Comment: I tried as u advised, and included all what is required in view, yet whilst the Model being accessed in view, it gives the context disposed error `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed`. When I debug in action method, the model hasn't selected any result set there as well.